# @INC not reading $PERL5LIB

Tags: perl, module, tcsh

I am trying to add a directory to my @INC array using `$PERL5LIB`. I am using tcsh shell and added the following command to my .cshrc script

```
set PERL5LIB = /home/user/perl5/lib/perl5
```

This seems to be working until the point that `$echo $PERL5LIB` shows the path added to `$PERL5LIB` variable. But running the script still gives me the same error:

```
Can't locate Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at regs_gen.pl line 55. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at regs_gen.pl line 55.
```

Apparently `$PERL5LIB` is not appended to the @INC array. I have been able to run my script using the -I command line argument with Perl as follows but I am looking for a more convenient solution.

```
perl -I /home/user/perl5/lib/perl5 scriptname.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

perl -V

Capital "-V" would look like your friend here documented in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Its trailing lines include useful parts of %ENV and @INC.

```
...
Built under linux
Compiled at Mar  1 2016 17:15:04
%ENV:
  PERL5LIB="/home/ron/lib"
  PERLBREW_BASHRC_VERSION="0.78"
  PERLBREW_HOME="/home/ron/.perlbrew"
  ... (more environment variables)
@INC:
  /home/ron/lib
  /etc/perl
  /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2
  /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2
  ... (more @INC paths)
  /usr/local/lib/site_perl
  .
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `export PERL5LIB=<path>` instead of `set PERL5LIB=<path>` (or the equivalent `PERL5LIB=<path>`) because the `export` command sets the variable for *all* shells, including the Perl subshell. Assignments using `set` (or nothing) do not set the variable for the new shell, which is what you need.